How to determine values of higher levels by previous level values?
I have an math issue to add levels from 100 to 1000, but only got values from previous level.
First way (which seemed not like true solution): my try was to determine scale of increase:
98 to 99: 1.48549052859962 / 1.47549052855247 = 1.006777407142667666027802785427;
97 to 98: 1.47549052855247 / 1.46549052844927 = 1.006823653861333136524863886226 ...
Second way (which seemed closer to solution) was to focus on delta (i.e. value99-value98) decrease:
0.01000000004715/0.0100000001032=0.99999999439500005784359940305405; 0.0100000001032/0.01000000021209=0.99999998911100023094479610189182; ...
The first code I had:
var rawData = new {startValue = 1.48549052859962, startValueChange = 1.006777407142667666027802785427,
  valueChangeDelta = 0.99999998911100023094479610189182};
int newLevels = 901;
double currentDeltaIncrease=rawData.startValueChange;
double currentValue=rawData.startValue;
for(int i = 1; i <= newLevels; i++) {
  currentDeltaIncrease*=rawData.valueChangeDelta;
  currentValue*=currentDeltaIncrease;
  Console.WriteLine(currentValue);
}

Because it is possible to have several values per level, I wanted to get rid of temporary storing in "current..."-variables:
for(int i = 1; i <= newLevels; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(rawData.startValue * Math.Pow(rawData.startValueChange * Math.Pow(rawData.valueChangeDelta, i), i));
}

Also tried to reconstruct values from 3 to 99 myself with level 2 for start data, but values are different.
The values from level 1 to 99

0.0534378655888462
0.103417958130935
0.150187142379338
0.193976721559392
0.235003285878962
0.273469522127392
0.309564985803977
0.343466837176423
0.37534054263011
0.40534054263011
0.433610887579783
0.460285842822386
0.485490463995477
0.509341143911967
0.531946132106459
0.553406028151031
0.573814249810801
0.593257477076532
0.611816073079128
0.629564482859128
0.646571610933278
0.662901178569855
0.678612061654716
0.693758610000949
0.708390948926613
0.722555263897232
0.736294069002583
0.749646460010777
0.762648352716717
0.775332707276717
0.787729739196369
0.799867117614635
0.811770151503618
0.82346196438055
0.834963658106136
0.846294466321637
0.857471898055803
0.868511872012087
0.879428842026456
0.890235914166456
0.900944955923168
0.911566697929096
0.922110828617022
0.932586082217298
0.943000320474056
0.953360608444246
0.963673284727383
0.973944026458308
0.984177909380165
0.994379463300165
1.00455272321654
1.01470127639133
1.02482830563044
1.0349366290194
1.04502873635108
1.05510682246933
1.06517281774116
1.07522841585884
1.0852750991623
1.0953141616623
1.10534672993426
1.11537378204347
1.12539616465293
1.13541460845618
1.14542974206903
1.15544210450583
1.16545215635806
1.17546028978574
1.18546683742443
1.19547208030443
1.20547625487165
1.21547955919368
1.22548215842847
1.23548418962761
1.24548576594038
1.25548698028024
1.26548790850992
1.27548861219737
1.28548914098981
1.29548953464981
1.30548982479273
1.31549003636185
1.3254901888738
1.33549029746387
1.34549037375782
1.35549042659397
1.36549046261702
1.3754904867624
1.385490502648
1.395490512888
1.40549051934176
1.41549052330894
1.4254905256807
1.43549052705509
1.44549052782396
1.45549052823718
1.46549052844927
1.47549052855247
1.48549052859962


Your question is missing a lot of context. What are these values? Where did they come from? What are you trying to do with them?

they are damage multipliers for skill advancements in a video game, so it must not be 100% perfect, just close to original increase.

Plotting those values in excel displays a curve that approaches a straight line. Excel has tools to fit a polynomial to the trend, which gives a function close to 0.05x - 0.0015x^2 + 0.01

If you plot the values, the curve approaches a line y = 0.001 * x + c. But there is probably some other component to the function that scales proportional to a / x.

Ok, I think this is close y = x/100 - 1/2 e^(-x/10) + 0.5.

Thank you! I think I can tweak the rest :)

After testing, the results of polynomial trend in Excel are not accurate. (Tested 1-50 data） You can use Jeremy's results. If your follow-up questions are solved, you can post it in the answer. See Can I answer my own question?  Just a reminder :)
